# How to use select.select Python

Tags: python, sockets, select

I'm currently making a guessing game in Python and I'm trying to use select.select to allow multiple clients to connect to my server but I cannot wrap my head around how to use select.select. I've look all over the internet but all the tutorials I've come across are for chat servers which I can't seem to relate to.

I was just wondering how I'd let multiple clients connect to my server through select.select. And also how would I send/receive data to/from individual clients using select.select

Comment: There may be some clues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194701/asynchronous-sockets-with-select-python It's not clear exactly what you are stuck on. Can you be more specific?

Comment: This may be help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605083/python-asyncore-keep-track-of-clients)

Answer (score 1):

> I've look all over the internet but all the tutorials I've come across
>   are for chat servers which I can't seem to relate to.

There's no difference between a chat server and game server regarding the use of [`select.select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html).

> I was just wondering how I'd let multiple clients connect to my server
>   through select.select.

You'd pass the server socket (which you called [`listen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen) on) in the *rlist* argument to `select`; if after return from `select` the server socket is in the first list (the objects that are ready for reading) of the returned triple of lists, you'd call [`accept`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) on the server socket and thus get the new client socket, which you'd append to the *rlist* in subsequent `select` calls.

> And also how would I send/receive data to/from individual clients
>   using select.select

If after return from `select` a client socket is in the first list (the objects that are ready for reading) of the returned triple of lists, you'd receive data by calling [`recv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) on that client socket.
You don't need to use `select` for writing; you'd just send data by calling [`send`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send).

See the question "[Handle multiple requests with select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572336/handle-multiple-requests-with-select)" for an example server.